# How would I generate a number from a list of defined numbers, rather than a range of numbers i.e. 1-10

Tags: vb.net

```
    Randomize()
    Dim gen_numb2 As Integer = CInt(Int((6 * Rnd()) + 1))
    Second_Number.Text = gen_numb2
```

[image]
I am using the code above to generate numbers which are being used in a child's maths program that i have been tasked to create. I just need to know how I can make the handler pick a number from a list I have defined. I need to do this because if I generate 2 numbers for a multiplication or division question, 72 x 32 is way too difficult for a child of 10 or 11. Instead I would like to generate the first number, which i have sorted already, and for the handler to pick the second number from a list of number like 1, 2, 5, 10; so that the maths question will be simpler for the child to work out (32 x 2). I'm sure it's simple enough, however I word it there seems to only be people asking for random numbers.

Comment: why not define 1 or 2 Lists(of Int) or arrays so you can control the values, then pick randomly.  You should use the Random class rather than the legacy Randomize/Rnd pair.  Actually, Random all by itself might work for you - the range is easily controlled.  (rand.Next(1, 39) and rand.Next(1, 10) or whatever range you need/want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a commenter above notes, I would approach it with a couple of constructs which have predefined values and then pick randomly from among them.

There is certainly room for improvements and alterations here, but this should [hopefully] get you started:

```
' Values available for selection.
Dim values1 As Integer() = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Dim values2 As Integer() = {16, 32, 64}

' Randomize the selection.
Dim randomizer As New Random

' Pick a value from each array.
Dim value1 As Integer = values1(randomizer.Next(values1.Length))
Dim value2 As Integer = values2(randomizer.Next(values2.Length))

' Present the problem.
Value1TextBox.Text = value1
Value2TextBox.Text = value2
' Store the answer in the Tag property so we can get to it easily.
AnswerTextBox.Tag = value1 * value2
```

Comment: that should be `randomizer.Next(values1.Length+1)`  the method used will probably prevent the last value(s) from being selected

Comment: I need it to be converted to string. Does this method not allow that?

Comment: @Plutonix - I'm pretty sure it works as is (as `Mod` will keep it <= the max). However, `Random.Next(Length)` would be more efficient as it (according to MSDN) picks a number between 0 and the value specified. I'll update the answer.

Comment: The `Mod` technique in this answer is not random. For most array sizes, it's skewed towards numbers towards the front of the array. No downvote, though, because this is probably good enough for a children's math program.

Comment: @Jurdun - The `String.Format` takes care of that... or are you referring to something else?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - What do you mean? `Mod` would just take the remainder, how would it alter the value?

Comment: it needs to be Length+1 because the Max param is EXCLUSIVE

Comment: @Plutonix - `Array(Array.Length)` is out of bounds. (Unless you have Option Base 1 on... is that even supported outside of VBA anymore?)

Comment: Have a look at my awful design. This is what i meant by it needing to be printed in string format to the left and right text box

Comment: It's common to lookup a random value in an array of size "n" by taking a random number "r" between 1 and some number larger than n, and fitting it to an array index by taking r Mod n. This is bad technique. It removes some of the randomness, because it skews results towards the front part of the array. That was the original code here. The edit fixed the problem.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - Interesting, I have never heard of that. Any particular reason as to why?

Comment: It skews results towards the front of the array. Imagine your array size is 4 (indices from 0 to 3), but you look at dice rolls (random values from 1 to 6). Results 1 to 4 will map evenly to array positions. Results 5 and 6 would match to array indices 0 and 1, making those position twice as common as positions 2 and 3. The results are no longer truly random.